# how can I center these 3 columns using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm relatively new to bootstrap I am trying to get the following 3 columns centered but they are off-center. The columns are col-md-3 each and the first one has an offset of 1 and I can understand why this is not centered but I can't work out how to get them centered.

I have created the example in [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/b7704OdBBk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue with your layout is that in order to center your 3 columns, you would have to offset the left column by 1.5 (half of the leftover columns):

```
// 12 Column Layout, 3 columns of col-md-3, offset of 1.5 needed (which isn't a class) 
12 - (3 + 3 + 3) = 3 / 2 = 1.5
```

Since that won't work (as `col-md-offset-1.5` isn't a class) I think you have 2 options here:

**Option 1**: Change your `col-md-3` to `col-md-4` and put it in a `container`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4 box">
    <div>                            
      <h4>box 1</h4>
      <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 box">
    <div>                            
      <h4>box 2</h4>
      <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 box">
    <div>                            
      <h4>box 3</h4>
      <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply Example 1](http://www.bootply.com/nFiV4776ZP)

**Option 2**: Change your `col-md-3` to `col-md-2` and `col-md-offset-1` to `col-md-offset-3` and put it in `container-fluid`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3 box">
    <div>                            
      <h4>box 1</h4>
      <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box">
    <div>                            
      <h4>box 2</h4>
      <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 box">
    <div>                            
      <h4>box 3</h4>
      <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply Example 2](http://www.bootply.com/AKTbW6fSKC)

Both methods change the layout so that the full 12 columns are taken up (or offset correctly), but one gives you a bit more space to work with.

For more info on the Bootstrap Grid see the [Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:
Try to use a div wrap row with offset 2. The 3th block will be divided by 2 each side (1.5). And make a fuild container wrapping all.

```
<div class="container-fluid">           
            <div class="row col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="col-md-3 box">
                    <div>                            
                            <h4>box 1</h4>
                            <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 box">
                    <div>                            
                            <h4>box 2</h4>
                            <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 box">
                    <div>                            
                            <h4>box 3</h4>
                            <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using flex properties :

```
.centered {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

And in your HTML :

```
<div class="centered">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>
            <h4>box 1</h4>
            <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>
            <h4>box 2</h4>
            <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>
            <h4>box 3</h4>
            <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not wrap the columns if you exceed 12 units except if you add `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using column in column, and don't forget to use sequence `container > row > col`

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-*"></div>
        <div class="col-md-*"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

```css
.box{
  background-color: lavender;
  border:1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
.column{
  background-color: AliceBlue;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-offset-1">

      <div class="col-md-4 box">
        <div class="column">                            
          <h4>box 1</h4>
          <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 box">
        <div class="column">                            
          <h4>box 2</h4>
          <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 box">
        <div class="column">                            
          <h4>box 3</h4>
          <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Honestly, this deserves a +. no additional css needed just wrap `col-xs-4` columns inside a `col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1` parent column.